# Trouble with move_uploaded_file on MAC

Tags: php, sql, macos, file-upload, xampp

I am working on an e-commerce project and I recently moved it over to a XAMPP setup on Mac. I was certain this code worked on my local windows XAMPP server. I am now getting an error when the image is uploaded:

**Warning: move_uploaded_file(admin/uploads/john.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/levelup/functions.php on line 238**

Here is my code:

```
$product_image          = escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
$image_temp_location    = escape_string($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

move_uploaded_file($image_temp_location, "admin/uploads/".$product_image); //LINE 238

$query = query("INSERT INTO products(product_title, product_category_id, product_price, product_description, short_desc, product_quantity, product_image) VALUES('{$product_title}', '{$product_category_id}','{$product_price}', '{$product_description}', '{$short_desc}', '{$product_quantity}', '{$product_image}')");
$last_id = last_id();
confirm($query);
set_message("New Product with id {$last_id} Just Added");
redirect("index.php?products");
  }
}
```

The directory definitely exists so I am not sure what's happening, this did work before..

Comment: Does the Apache user have permission to write to that directory?